# How to programmatically set Excel user name to host name

Tags: excel, powershell, batch-file, vbscript

I would like to know whether it is possible to programmatically set the user name in Excel 2013 to the computers host name using any one of the tagged scripting languages. Browsed the web for a while now but did not find any useful hint to get this working.

Remark: Excel is closed so it should be a standalone script (no VBA).

Any answer is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
Sub ChangeUserName()
Dim UserDomain As String
Dim ComputerName As String
Set wshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
ComputerName = wshNetwork.ComputerName
MsgBox Application.UserName
Application.UserName = ComputerName
MsgBox Application.UserName
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I cannot use VBA (see my remark)

Comment: Ah sorry. I didn't notice that. My apologies.

Comment: Well, it may help someone else in the future who requires a VBA implementation :)